# Advanced Java console input

Tags: java, brainfuck, esoteric-languages

As a self-practice, I'm making a [BF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) interpreter in Java that does I/O through the console.  For the most part it's fine, however, as you might be aware, BF takes input one character at a time, including newlines.  This means that as far as I know the standard console input libraries won't work, because they take in entire strings, and then ask for a return at the end.  I want `,` to take in the next keystroke that fits into a `char` **without** printing it when it is typed.  So when BF asks for input, and you type in `a`, it takes in the `a` but doesn't show it in the console unless the BF program outputs `a` itself later.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using JLine http://jline.sourceforge.net

The `Terminal` class has a `disableEcho()` method to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own console output/input using a textArea in a frame and a keyListener

Comment: He is writing a command line tool, Swing components won't help there.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `java.io.Console` - you can read a string w/o echo with `readPassword()`. It is still line oriented though, so you won't receive anything until user presses Enter. Another possible disadvatage is that there may be no console - depends on the way app is launched.